# package dependency conflict

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I'm currently developing a small test project using angular meteor. How ever I tried to add the [angular-ui calendar package](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/) and it breaks my project.

I get a warning: "WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.".

And all my modules causing the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: _angular2.default.module(...).component is not a function"

I've figuered, I believe, it out to be caused by angular-ui beeing dependant on angular 1.4.8 and my project is using angular 1.5.5.

I've tried to manipulate the package file and move the "angularui:ui-calendar"-package to the top with no effect.

Is there a workaround availible for dependancy conflicts?

Edit: 
[Repo of minimal code](https://github.com/gurugutten/angularUITest)

Comment: Your error is referencing Angular 2.  Where is that coming from?  There's too much info that you're not showing us.  Can you provide a repo showing an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  If it helps you I can provide a sample app showing angular-meteor working with ui-calendar, but that won't resolve the specific conflict that you're experiencing.

Comment: @MarkLeiber Question edited with repo. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

The console error says:

> foo.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: _angular2.default.module(...).component
>   is not a function ... foo.js line 14

As you said, that's because of the angular version being used.  Edit the version in `.meteor/versions`:

```
angular:angular@1.5.3_1
```

That resolves your error.  When you start trying to use the calendar you may find issues if you don't pay attention to the note on https://atmospherejs.com/angularui/ui-calendar, which says:

> **Important** 
>   Include FullCalendar if the source is missing in your app:
>   `meteor add planettraining:jquery-fullcalendar`

Comment: I am actually aware of the problem in regards to the use of component(Introduced in angular 1.5). Everything works fine as long as i remove the usage of the angular ui calendar package. See the readMe in repo. I just find it strange that my angular dependency (1.5.5) defined in /package.json is overridden to angular 1.4.8 when adding the calendar package to the project. As you see, even if you stop using component() the warning: "WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once." still persists

Comment: I see what you're saying.  Your versions file is specifying 1.4.8.  Updating it to a 1.5 release fixed it for me.

Comment: How did you manage to update to 1.5, everytime I try meteor adjust it back to 1.4.8 again.

Comment: Yes, but as soon as i build. the versions file get changed back to 1.4.8

Comment: What versions do you get if you run these in your project directory: `meteor npm list angular` and `meteor npm list angular-meteor`